# Vector derivative with power of two in it

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis

I want to compute the gradient of the following function with respect to $\beta$

$$L(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \phi(x_i)^T \cdot \beta)^2$$

Where $\beta$, $y_i$ and $x_i$ are vectors. The $\phi(x_i)$ simply adds additional coefficients, with the result that $\beta$ and $\phi(x_i)$ are both $\in \mathbb{R}^d$

Here is my approach so far:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} L(\beta) &= \sum_{i=1}^n ( \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} y_i - \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}( \phi(x_i)^T \cdot \beta))^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n ( 0 - \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}( \phi(x_i)^T \cdot \beta))^2\\
&= - \sum_{i=1}^n ( \partial \phi(x_i)^T \cdot \beta + \phi(x_i)^T \cdot \partial \beta))^2\\
&= - \sum_{i=1}^n ( 0 \cdot \beta + \phi(x_i)^T \cdot \textbf{I}))^2\\
&= - \sum_{i=1}^n ( \phi(x_i)^T \cdot \textbf{I}))^2\\
\end{align*}

But what to do with the power of two? Have I made any mistakes? Because $\phi(x_i)^T \cdot \textbf I$ seems to be $\in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times d}$

$$= - 2 \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(x_i)^T\\$$

Comment: Do you know about the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Sure, I added something to the end of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector differentiation can be tricky when you're not used to it. One way to get around that is to use [summation notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_convention) until you're confident enough to perform the derivatives without it.

To begin with, let's define $X_i=\phi(x_i)$ since it will save some typing, and let $X_{ni}$ be the $n$th component of the vector $X_i$.

Using summation notation, you have

$$\begin{align}
L(\beta) 
& = (y_i-X_{mi}\beta_m)(y_i - X_{ni}\beta_n) \\
& = y_i y_i - 2 y_i X_{mi} \beta_m + X_{mi}X_{ni}\beta_m\beta_n
\end{align}$$

To take the derivative with respect to $\beta_k$, you do

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta_k} L(\beta)
& = -2 y_i X_{mi} \delta_{km} + 2 X_{mi} X_{ni} \beta_n \delta_{km} \\
& = -2 X_{mi} \delta_{km} (y_i - X_{ni} \beta_n) \\
& = -2 X_{ki} (y_i - X_{ni} \beta_n)
\end{align}$$

which you can then translate back into vector notation:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta} L(\beta) = -2 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i (y_i - X_i^T\beta)
$$

Does that help?

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks for the explanation in an alternative notation, this will help me in the future a lot.

Comment: I have redone the derivation in my original notation, and I found it quite easy, by just computing the derivative of $(y - x^T \cdot \beta) = -x$ and then applying the product rule which gets me to the same result as your final line.

Comment: Glad to hear it!